# Foreach loop inside for loop runs only once

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have got a foreach loop iterating over metalname array, which is nested inside a for loop, the foreach loop is coming from a seperate array, the issue is, during first iteration of for loop, the for each loop prints the values, but during next iteration of for loop, the foreach prints nothing.
whereas, for rest of the fields, there is no problem, they get printed on all iteratins.

```
$product = GetProduct();
$metal_name = get_metal();
$count = count($product);
<?php for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) { ?>
            <div class="form-group">

              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-2">Choose Metal</label>

              <div class="col-lg-10">

              <select class="form-control input-lg" name="metal_name[]">
              <option value=''>Select Metal Name</option>    
                <?php
                    foreach ($metal_name as $r) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $r['metal_id'];?>" <?php if($r['metal_id'] == $product[$i]['metal']){echo "selected='selected'";}?>><?php echo ucfirst($r['metal_name']);?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>

              </div>

            </div>
 <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Product ID</label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product[$i]['id'];?>">

            </div>

          </div>


          <div class="form-group">

              <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Charges Per Gram</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">

                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gram_price[]" value="<?php echo $product[$i]['per_gram_price'];?>">

              </div>

          </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one thing on your forth line:

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) { ?>
```

You didn't close out of PHP in your code above when you are getting your product and such. So this will give you some error.

In terms of your loop, a while loop is better for database work.

Here, I fixed it up for you. There were a few typos:

```
<?php
$product = GetProduct();
$metal_name = get_metal();
$count = count($product);
or($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) { ?>
        <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-2">Choose Metal</label>

          <div class="col-lg-10">

          <select class="form-control input-lg" name="metal_name[]">
          <option value=''>Select Metal Name</option>
          <?php
                foreach ($metal_name as $r) {
          ?>
          <option value="
              <?php
                  echo $r['metal_id'];
                  if($r['metal_id'] == $product[$i]['metal']){
                      echo "selected='selected'";
                      echo ucfirst($r['metal_name']);
                  }
              ?>
           </option>
           </select>

           </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

        <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Product ID</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product[$i]['id'];?>">

        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Charges Per Gram</label>

          <div class="col-sm-10">

              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gram_price[]" value="<?php echo $product[$i]['per_gram_price']; ?>">

          </div>

      </div>
```

I fixed up your code a bit for you, try this out.